# Convert h264 compressed CMSampleBuffer to FFmpeg AVPacket

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ffmpeg, core-video

I'm trying to export the CMSampleBufferRef from VTCompressionSession to FFmpeg processable AVPacket.
I saw the FFmpeg provides function `av_read_frame()` to get packet out from an encoded file.  So using this, I can successfully get an AVPacket from an H264 encoded file(eg. using AVAssetWritter).  So I went into the av_read_frame() [implementation](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avfoundation_8m_source.html) and saw it reads out an imageBuffer from sampleBuffer.
So I tried to use the same implementation in the VTCompressionSessionCallback function

```
void VTCompressionOutputCallback(
    void *outputCallbackRefCon, 
    void *sourceFrameRefCon, 
    OSStatus status, 
    VTEncodeInfoFlags infoFlags,
    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer) {
NSLog(@"VTCompressionSession Callback");
CMBlockBufferRef blockBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer);
CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
}
```

But it turns out the pixelBuffer here is nil, and I only get blockBuffer as valid output.  So how do I get the frame out from the blockBuffer.  Or more specifically, how do i get AVPacket using the blockBuffer here.

Comment: I am having the same issue on Yosmite